# Is there a way to get the content of specific mails from the Thunderbird Inbox file in bash?

Tags: bash, thunderbird

I want to open the standard `Inbox` file that Thunderbird creates and read out mails (text/body suffices) by specific properties like sender, date or subject.

I can get the content of the file via `less Inbox`, but that ouput is completely unstructured and has no UTF8 encoding. I don't see any way for filtering for specific mails and displaying/processing their content.

I have searched some time for a solution, but I could not find any hint how to even approach this. But since Thunderbird can distinguish the mails in this file, it surely must be possible somehow.

Comment: What is the question according to [ask] which you would like an answer to? Note that "What is the specification for the Thunderbird mail file format? Is it proprietary?" is not. Be careful to stay on-topic, because requesting such an external resource is specifically off-topic on StackOverflow. And "No idea." is not a question, even less an on-topic one, it lacks focus.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. My goal is to write a bash file that allows me to filter the mails I received and downloaded via Thunderbird by specific criteria. Does that clear things up? I hope this is not off-topic for SO.

Comment: google how to install and use [formail](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/procmail/formail.1.en.html) and/or [procmail](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/procmail/procmail.1.en.html), I forget which of them does what. A few online tutorials exist.